# Function call within a for loop terminates the loop?

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing a funny issue with JavaScript. I have a feeling this could have something to do with Closures, which, I admit, I am not really comfortable with.

**Problem**
It seems that calling a function from within results in a premature termination of the loop. I tried running the same loop without the function call and console.log() outputs the counter accurately suggesting the function call is breaking the loop.

Could someone suggest a possible fix? I have the code pasted here:

```
AbstractModel.prototype.deactivateContext   = function(context){

  for(i=0;i<this.asset.length;i++){
      if(this.asset[i].context == context){
        this.asset[i].deactivate();
        console.log(i);
        this.notify(this.asset[i],"REFRESHASSETS");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you call this method? (*Did* you call the method?) This is just a method definition; it won't actually run the body.

Comment: Which particular function call seems to be the problem? There are 3 in that loop.

Comment: AbstractModel will have a method called deactivateContext. Looks like you have Assets object with method called deactivate. If you show us the invocations and more code, we will be able to comment better

Comment: The last one seems to be the problem, commenting it out allows the loop to complete its lifecycle.

Comment: @SPI Then our next request is to show the definition of `notify`.

Comment: Oh, I found it. i is not declared. i is coming from global context.

Comment: You forgot to declare "i" with `var`. If the other function *also* uses "i" to control a loop, then you'll have problems.

Comment: Sure, let me edit my post with more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` is not optional

You proabbly have a global `i` in the other method. Declare your variables to the correct scope.

```
for (var i=0; i<this.asset.length; i++) {
     ^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, the issue is probably a side effect altering either "i" or this.asset.length

Comment: I am using 'i' in the other function (notify) as well without explicitly declaring it there which would explain why the loop ends early. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Please declare i in the following function, like

```
AbstractModel.prototype.deactivateContext   = function(context){

  for(var i=0;i<this.asset.length;i++){
      if(this.asset[i].context == context){
        this.asset[i].deactivate();
        console.log(i);
        this.notify(this.asset[i],"REFRESHASSETS");
      }
  }
}
```

Looks like i is getting modified to a higher number in the notify function, when it returns from notify the `for` check is exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the call to the `notify` function in try catch. If you are saying that when you remove the call, output of counter prints as expected then the only explanation would be that your function is throwing an exception. Try this:

```
 for(i=0;i<this.asset.length;i++){
      if(this.asset[i].context == context){
        this.asset[i].deactivate();
        console.log(i);
        try {
          this.notify(this.asset[i],"REFRESHASSETS");
        } catch(e) {
           alert(e);
           console.log(e);
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: +1, that's a really smart debugging tip but the issue was resolved by declaring the counter explicitly. I am using 'i' in the other functino (notify) as well without explicitly declaring it which would explain why the loop ends early. Thanks!

Comment: oh cool, sorry did notice that you are not declaring var explicitly.